# Azure Automation Webhook - Twilio StatusCallback not arriving in JSON

Tags: json, powershell, twilio, webhooks, azure-automation

I'm trying to implement a solution which automatically calls someone when a certain event occurs, based on Twilio, Azure Automation and SCOM. Furthermore, it shall be possible for someone to call a number, and the same process is triggered.

The Twilio Account/Phonenumber is set up and works fine. When I do a call to the Twilio Number I successfully receive HTTP POST on my Azure Automation Webhook and the Runbook is fired.

The only problem I'm facing right now, is that I cannot make use of the cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json` to extract the WebhookBody.

This is the error I get when using the cmdlet:

> ConvertFrom-JSON : Invalid JSON primitive: Called. At line:13 char:11
>   + $Inputs = ConvertFrom-JSON $webhookdata.RequestBody
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

And this is the Input arriving on the Azure Automation Webhook from Twilio:

> {"WebhookName":"Twilio
>   Endpoint","RequestBody":"Called=%2B41815880262&ToState=Chur&CallerCountry=CH&Direction=inbound&Timestamp=Fri%2C%2010%20Feb%202017%2009%3A07%3A35%20%2B0000&CallbackSource=call-progress-events&CallerState=&ToZip=&SequenceNumber=0&CallSid=CA7c152287d945595fe600614fe7778f8a&To=%2B41815880262&CallerZip=&ToCountry=CH&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=completed&Duration=1&From=%2BMYTELNUZMBER&CallDuration=8&AccountSid=MYSID&CalledCountry=CH&CallerCity=&Caller=%2Bmybnumber&FromCountry=CH&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=Chur&FromZip=&FromState=","RequestHeader":{"Cache-Control":"max-age=259200","Connection":"close","Accept":"*/*","Host":"s2events.azure-automation.net","User-Agent":"TwilioProxy/1.1","X-Twilio-Signature":"pq2jYVGN3H5LmanwId0xCvp69tM=","x-ms-request-id":"bc1cf55a-33b2-4046-a343-199d1a7fac4a"}}

When I simply output the WebHook Data with this cmd, I can see that the Twilio Repsonse looks somewhat strange (Heade looks good though):

```
$WebhookName = $WebhookData.WebhookName
$WebhookHeaders = $WebhookData.RequestHeader
$WebhookBody = $WebhookData.RequestBody

Write-Output $WebhookHeaders
Write-Output $WebhookBody
```

**Output:**

> Cache-Control      : max-age=259200 Connection         : close Accept 
>   : */* Host               : s2events.azure-automation.net User-Agent
>   : TwilioProxy/1.1 X-Twilio-Signature : xmEbt23prT+W8zJrRZE5pdKullE=
>   x-ms-request-id    : bdca412c-584e-42ba-acbb-969cdf9c1ec0
>
> Called=%2B41815880262&ToState=Chur&CallerCountry=CH&Direction=inbound&Timestamp=Wed%2C%2008%20Feb%202017%2013%3A18%3A27%20%2B0000&CallbackSource=call-progress-events&CallerState=&ToZip=&SequenceNumber=0&CallSid=CALLSID&To=%2B41815880262&CallerZip=&ToCountry=CH&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=completed&Duration=1&From=%2BMYNUMBER&CallDuration=7&AccountSid=MYSID&CalledCountry=CH&CallerCity=&Caller=%2BMYBNUMBER&FromCountry=CH&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=Chur&FromZip=&FromState=

Does anybody have an idea what I could do instead of writing my own "Converter" to get the values from the TWILIO HTTP POST? Or may I be doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio sends a webhook request to your URL it is not encoded as JSON. This is why your JSON conversion is failing.

[Twilio sends the data as either URL encoded parameters in the body of a POST request or URL query parameters for GET requests](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous). This is the same as if the request were made by the submission of a form in a browser.

I'm not familiar with Azure cmdlets but if there is one for parsing URL encoded data, then you'll want to use that instead. Alternatively, @4c74356b41 has provided a decent implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought so that I might have a misexpectation regarding Twilios responses/requests.

Answer (score 3):

So, I think I understood your problem. You are doing it slightly wrong: `$webhook` data is already an object, which has everything you need:

```
$WebhookData.WebhookName
$WebhookData.RequestHeader
$WebhookData.RequestBody
```

You just need to parse `RequestBody` into something meaningful:

```
$data = @{ };

foreach ($item in $WebhookData.RequestBody.Split('&')) {
    try {
        $item = $item.Split('=');
        $data.Add($item[0], [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlDecode($item[1]))           
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning -Message ('Possible null parameter value for {0}' -f $item[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much for the provided function :)

Comment: you should mark this as an answer in that case ;) @y_maurer

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to, but I guess now i've found the button ;)

Comment: I guess you've marked the other answer as the right one ;)) @y_maurer